# How can I set the buttons to fill each half of row?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

In my android application I have two buttons, situated on a row and above them, is displayed a map. I want each button to occupy half of row. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Currently my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Program" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Afisaza toate statiile" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnProgram"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAfisareStatii" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0ws8opHdf-pIbZUa916nju81kSSlPRK4Wbg_0vg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:layout_above="@id/btnProgram">
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linear layout and layout_weight:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Program" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnProgram"
            android:text="Afisaza toate statiile" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAfisareStatii" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview" />

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_container"
        android:apiKey="0ws8opHdf-pIbZUa916nju81kSSlPRK4Wbg_0vg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But why are you putting the webviews below the buttons which themselves are aligned to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I have an error at this line: android:layout_width="match_parent". The error is: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').

Comment: then put in fill_parent. Both values mean the same but fill_parent was renamed to match_parent since API version 8.

Comment: Still don't work for me. I get an error, something like: Application stopped unexpectedly

Comment: remove android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnProgram" from the button and clean+ rebuild the project.

Comment: I added webviews because when I clicked on a button opens a PDF, and when I click on the other button an website opens

Comment: Now there are not displayed the buttons, only the map

Comment: it looks fine in my eclipse. I can see the buttons below the MapView.

Comment: I will put the application on the device to see how it works, because in emulator I can not see the buttons

Comment: the same thing on device, I can not see the buttons

Comment: all answers you got are correct. Use a horizontal linear layout in combination with layout_weights. Applying this solution to you layout xml should be a very simply task. Heck we even provided you with ready to use layouts. The problem are the webviews. They overlap the button bar! If you dont show them all the time use a ViewSwitcher or set their visibility to Visibility.GONE.

Comment: I moved the code for WebViews and MapView before the LinearLayout that contains the buttons, and now works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Put your buttons in a `LinearLayout` and assign `layout_weight` to them.  Then put this LinearLayout to the bottom of your RelativeLayout.

```
<LinearLayout layout_width="fill_parent" layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Program" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
        android:layout_width="wrap_fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Afisaza toate statiile" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did that, but now is displayed only the map, the buttons no longer appears

Answer (score 1):

Place both buttons inside a `LinearLayout` and set the `android:orientation="horizontal"`

something as below. Make sure you have `weight` attribute for buttons

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATED

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAfisareStatii" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0ws8opHdf-pIbZUa916nju81kSSlPRK4Wbg_0vg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" 
         android:layout_weight="1">
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1">
          <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Program" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAfisareStatii"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Afisaza toate statiile" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnProgram" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did that, but now is displayed only the map, the buttons no longer appears

Comment: I chacked your update, the buttons are displayed as I want, but don't look well. In the first half of the page is not displayed anything, in the middle is shown a bit of map and buttons and in the bottom is not displayed anything

Comment: I edited the above message. I plus I added webviews because when I clicked on a button opens a PDF, and when I click on the other button an website opens. But before I click the buttons I don't want to appear the webviews